# `ls\` logs out of terminal session?

Tags: terminal, zsh, ls

Like many, I have an `alias ll=ls -l[.]+` set.

A moment ago, I typed `ll` and then accidentally hit `\` on the way to return.

I hit return again to finish the command (on the continued line prompt), expecting to see the usual output of `ll`.

Instead I got:

```
  % ll\
  %

  [Process completed]
```

Woah! What happened? It was as if I hit Ctrl-d, but I definitely didn't (I repeated the exercise).

This doesn't happen with other programs (e.g. `echo`) but does with `ls` (so not a weird `alias` issue).

This occurs with `zsh 5.0.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0)`, though not all versions or platforms as Tom mentions in comments.

What causes this, and why (if it's "not a bug, a feature")?

Comment: After quickly installing `zsh` to test, I find that `ls\<enter><enter>` hangs until I get impatient and Ctrl-C it, at which point I see the prompt again. Doesn't happen with anything except `ls`. Nothing unusual happens in bash.

Comment: @TomHunt Interesting. This is completely repeatable for me, so maybe it varies by platform/version in `zsh`.. weird though.

Comment: Either way, seems likely to be a `zsh` bug specifically. I wonder if `zsh` has code to treat `ls` specially?

Comment: Does this happen if you run `zsh -f` and just set this alias? By the way, what is the alias supposed to accomplish, other than printing `zsh: no matches found: -l[.]+`? What is printing the `[Process completed]`: is it the program that started zsh? If so you've probably hit a zsh bug that makes it crash.

Comment: @Gilles Yes, because as stated it happens with just `ls`, I should probably remove reference to the aliasing from OP, it turns out not to be relevant.

I didn't mean literally "[.]+", I meant `ll=ls -l` is the common part, plus whatever other options people might have. e.g. I have `alias ll=ls -GFhl`.

Running in a new `zsh -f` crashes out with a seg fault, so it is a bug - thanks for that pointer! (no pun intended..)

Comment: Actually it's more subtle than that - I have an alias on `ls` too, so only just realised. This bug occurs if and only if there is an alias set. `zsh -f && ls\ ` is fine, `zsh -f && alias ls=ls && ls\ ` is not.

Comment: I've now reported this as a bug to the zsh-workers mailing list.